muirichtexteditor not resetting default value after save
I am using MUIRichTextEditor (mui-rte version 2.0.1) in a chat room in Vite. The code I have for the user to input new data is
      <MUIRichTextEditor
        label="Type next message or insert a picture..."
        ref={ref}
        defaultValue={text}
        onSave={save}
        controls={[...]}

where
const [text, setText] = useState(emptyContentState);

  const save = (newMessage) => {
    // service request to database to save message
    setText(emptyContentState);
  };

const emptyContentState = JSON.stringify(
  convertToRaw(EditorState.createEmpty().getCurrentContent()));

The first time the editor is displayed, the input field is blank. After a save, the field stays as the value that was last entered. Seems like to should be cleared.
What am I doing wrong?
I've tried removing the defaultValue and there is no effect
